# Batch file to autorun when computer is inactive

Tags: batch-file, autorun

As the title says, I want a batch file to autorun when the computer (mouse, keyboard, etc ...) are stopped (inactive) for at least 3 minutes.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Task Scheduler.

Create a new task with an "on idle" trigger, and specify the desired idle time on the Conditions tab of the new task.

Specify your batch file on the Actions tab.